# Magento 2.4.4: Error on magento.cron.log

Tags: magento2, cron

I am getting thi error in my magento.cron.log.

```
preg_split(): Argument #2 ($subject) must be of type string, array given../html/vendor/magento/module-cron/Model/Schedule.php(107): preg_split('#\\s+#', Array, -1, 1)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have create any custom code for cron job related ?

Comment: No. I have disabled all the 3rd party extensions.

Comment: Your php version is above 8?

Comment: Yes it is 8.1.12